# Why does the HAVING clause need to come after the GROUP-BY?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to understand logically why we need a HAVING clause after the GROUP-BY ?

```
SELECT name
FROM actor
WHERE id IN (

   SELECT Actorid
   FROM casting
   WHERE ord = 1

GROUP BY actorid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 29

)
ORDER BY name asc
```

It hasn't clicked yet to me, that why is the following incorrect :

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 29
GROUP BY actorid
```

Comment: Why does `order`  need a `by` after it and why can't I just do `by order`. Because!

Comment: @juergend - Hmm, yea I see that point

Comment: Because that's what the defined syntax is...?

Comment: Because H comes after G, alphabetically?

Comment: There's method in the madness in this particular case -- `HAVING` applies to the result of your grouping, so in this particular, unusual case, SQL is following the chronological order of the query steps.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - Gotcha, I went ahead and made an answer from this.. for my self-reference. I know it's easy-peasy but it was confusing to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because the SQL will group records before it evaluates the HAVING clause.

It is mainly the SQL syntax, however it makes intuitive sense, as Jeroen points out :

> HAVING applies to the result of your grouping, so in this particular,
>   unusual case, SQL is following the chronological order of the query
>   steps.

[10 Tips for Sorting SQL - TechRepublic](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techrepublic.com%2Farticle%2F10-tips-for-sorting-grouping-and-summarizing-sql-data%2F&ei=BsxsVP3qPIeuyASzyYGwBA&usg=AFQjCNESLIVHck5Vq6eBSfc6Nl5DR16u0Q&sig2=HPJATK_VWiSDOGInuZiAUQ&bvm=bv.80120444,d.aWw)